# Get every item matches the condition in a map with iterator

Tags: c++, dictionary, lambda, iterator

I would like to get all the items that match the condition. As far I am able to do is code de iterator, but I don't know how to keep going. This is my code:

```
map<string, Device*>::iterator it;
    it = find_if(
        devicesMap.begin(),
        devicesMap.end(),
        [](Device* item)->bool{return item->Name() == ""; });
```

This code would get the first item matches the condition, because I am using it in another part of the code, but if there were more than one, how could I go through all of them without getting through whole map?

Comment: First of all you need to read more about [`find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_if), especially what the argument to the predicate function is, because for a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) it's *not* type you think it is. Then for your problem, maybe you could use [`copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_if) to copy to a new container?

Comment: In the other part of the code I was meaning, it is true that I am not using `find_if` with `std::map` but with `std::list`. Answering your question, no, I can create a copy of the objects because I want to modify them. I want to get all of them which don't have name and write them it.

Comment: Well you could put them (using `copy_if`) in a container of *pointers* to the actual object.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I resolved the question thanks to @Joachim in this way:

```
copy_if(originalMap->begin(),
            originalMap->end(),
            inserter(auxMap, auxMap.end()),
            [auxTimevar](std::pair<string, SnmpHwObject*> n)->bool
        {
            seconds sec = chrono::duration_cast<seconds>(n.second->TimeStamp());
            return (rightNow - sec.count() >= TEN_SECONDS);
        });
```

I post it, if someone is interesting in it.
I have checked the algorithm with a simple `for` with its `if`condition and it works.